# How can I set application name when accessing SQL Server DB using Node.js mssql module?

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I'm using the mssql module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) to access SQL Server databases. This is working pretty well, I can read/write/execute etc.

I can assign a login to the service I'm using, however I would also like to set the Application name property of the connection to something other than node-mssql, e.g. MyService.

I'm using a JSON config. file of the form

```
{
   "user": "my_user",
   "password": "my_password",
   "server": "my_server",
   "database": "my_database",
   "port": 1433
}
```

Is is possible to add an additional property "application" or similar for this purpose? I can't find this in the docs for mssql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the link you provided it discusses an option for passing in a classic connection string.

> In addition to configuration object there is an option to pass config
>   as a connection string. Two formats of connection string are
>   supported.

You are able to specific an `Application Name` in a standard SQL Server connection string.
`"Application Name=MyAppName;"`

Also, if you keep scrolling in the link you provided, there is an option for setting the application name using TDS. This of course assumes you are using the TDS driver.

`options.appName - Application name used for SQL server logging.`

Perhaps try something like this in your JSON?

```
{
   "user": "my_user",
   "password": "my_password",
   "server": "my_server",
   "database": "my_database",
   "port": 1433
   "options.appName": "name"

}
```

or

```
{
   "user": "my_user",
   "password": "my_password",
   "server": "my_server",
   "database": "my_database",
   "port": 1433
   "options": {
     appName: name
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, that is one option I would explore, I'm just wondering if I can keep the existing JSON configuration.

Comment: I did see the ability to include an `options` array in your JSON config. The site is not clear on what options are available however, except the `encrypt` option for Azure.

Comment: Yeah, and I've tried a couple of settings, however I can't seem to find the magic one!

Comment: As a matter of interest I've tried using a traditional connection string with application name specified, however this doesn't appear to be honored.

Comment: The "options": {
     appName: name
   } structure works, thanks again!